# ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff 'DataSource is not valid. Please check you Datasource to proceed.'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript, postgresql, datasource

I'm trying to pull my data from database. but I'm getting this error in console. What should I do in this situation?

service.ts

```
  getToken(){
    return "82561747775276843117"
    // return localStorage.getItem('token')
  }

  getCurrentUserId() {
    // return localStorage.getItem('userId')
    return "50085825682871846345"
  }

  getDatas() {
    const body = {
      Token: this.getToken(),
      DataStoreId: '54545651247771316477 ',
      Operation: 'read',
      Encrypted: 1951,
      Data: 'select * from "postgres".public.quest',
    };
    return this.http.post(baseUrl + 'Application/DataOps', body).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        return response.message;
      })
    );
  }
```

and main.ts:

```
questArray:Quest[]=[]
.
.
.

getQuest(){
  this.connect.getDatas().subscribe(res=>{
    this.questArray=res

  })
```

and this is my error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vclA2.png)

Line 37 is the code in the ts file I wrote above.
Line 27 is the part where I call this function in ngOnInit.

Comment: In `this.connect.getDatas().subscribe(res=>{` the value `res` which is retrieved from the backend is not an array but it is treated as if it were an array. That's probably the reason for your error.

Comment: Post the response.

Comment: `res` is an array and the angular algorithm is not able to put it into state.

Comment: what should i do in the code?